# Can I check if someone downloaded my code?

Tags: security, logging, gitlab

A old user account had access to one of my repos and i didnt notice. Can I check in the logs if he downloaded my repo in any way? Thanks for the help

Answer (score 1):

If you have a premium subscription you can view logged events in the audit logs. These events include project repository downloads.

https://docs.gitlab.com/ee/administration/audit_events.html#project-events